# Vundle - E492: Not an editor command: PluginInstall

Tags: ubuntu, vim, ubuntu-14.04, vundle

I am having trouble getting Vundle for Vim to work (I am on Ubuntu 14.04). Here the relevant part from my .vimrc

```
  4 " For Vundle$                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  5 filetype off$                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  6 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle$                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  7 call vundle#rc()$                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  8 $                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  9 " Let Vundle manage Vandle$                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 10 Plugin 'gmarik/vundle'$                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 11 $                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 12 Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'$                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 13 Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'$                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 14 Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'$                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 15 Plugin 'tpope/vim-rails.git'$                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 16 Plugin 'tomtom/tcomment_vim'$                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 17 Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'$                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 18 Plugin 'tomasr/molokai'$                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 19 Plugin 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'$                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 20 Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'$                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 21 Plugin 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'$                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 22 Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'$                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 23 Plugin 'kchmck/vim-coffee-script'$                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 24 Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'$                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 25 Plugin 'skalnik/vim-vroom'$                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 26 Plugin 'tpope/vim-dispatch'$                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 27 $                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 28 call vundle#end()$                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 29 $                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 30 filetype plugin indent on$
```

Why does it throw an error `E492: Not an editor command: PluginInstall` ?

Comment: This post fixed it for me; Cloning into a plugin directory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017366/vim-error-e492-not-an-editor-command-plugininstall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that `call vundle#rc()` seems to be deprecated. Using call `vundle#begin()` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing

```
call vundle#end()
```

between lines 26 and 28.

Note that Vundle's API [has changed](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim/blob/master/doc/vundle.txt#L371-L395): it's not `:Bundle*` anymore, it's `:Plugin*`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. I get "line 7: E117: Unknown function: vundle#rc" followed by a list of all Plugins and "line 28: E117: Unknown function: vundle#end". I updated the original question with the changed config file.

Comment: Even after using vundle#end i still get the same error

Answer (score 4):

This error message came up may be because your vi is not vim.

try install the vim first. If it let you, that means is it the problem.

```
sudo yum install vim
```

set alias

```
alias vi=vim
```

Then try run vi and

```
:PluginInstall
```

Answer (score 3):

This happened to my work machine (Windows) because I was using Cygwin ViM. The problem was that when I cloned Vundle.vim it used Windows style line endings and the Vundle plugin wasn't loading. I had to run `find ~/.vim -type f -iname '*.vim' -exec dos2unix {} \+` to convert my files to unix line endings before it worked.

This assumes you have [dos2unix](https://superuser.com/questions/612435/cygwin-dos2unix-command-not-found) installed.

Comment: You're awesome!