# Vim Error E492 - Not an editor command: PluginInstall

Tags: macos, vim-plugin, vundle

I am trying to install Vundle on my Macvim. I followed the following [link](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) to get Vundle. I also configured my .vimrc file. But when I try PluginInstall, I get the following error.

```
E492: Not an editor command: PluginInstall
```

My .vimrc contains the following:

```
  1 set nocompatible    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845557/in-a-vimrc-is-set-nocc
    ompatible-completely-useless
  2
  3 " https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim
  4 filetype off                  " required
  5
  6 " set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
  7 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
  8 call vundle#begin()
  9 " alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
 10 "call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')
 11
 12 " let Vundle manage Vundle, required
 13 Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
 14
 15 " All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
 16 call vundle#end()            " required
 17 filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

My vim directory:

```
Username-MacBook-Pro:bundle u1$ pwd
/Users/u1/.vim/bundle
Username-MacBook-Pro:bundle u1$ ls
Vundle.vim
```

I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185580/vundle-e492-not-an-editor-command-plugininstall) stackoverflow post. But it didn't solve my problem. Why does it throw such an error and how can I find what exactly is my issue.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I had to install Vundle into Plugin directory instead of Bundle. It solved the issue.

```
git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/plugin/Vundle.vim
```

Comment: [Came here after this Digital Ocean doc lead me astray](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-vundle-to-manage-vim-plugins-on-a-linux-vps).

Comment: Confirmed this solution on Catalina/Brew.  Thanks SyncMaster.

Comment: Bless your soul.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the output of :version

```
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
```

Note which vimrc file you are using, say you are configuring `$HOME/vimrc`, but vim is reading `$HOME/.vimrc` (without dot at filename)

This happened to me.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This was the problem for me. I have a funky thing where I import vim configs into `~/.vimrc` with lines like, `:source $HOME/.vim/vimrc_default.vim`. Silly, but I was looking at `.vim/` and failed to notice `~/.vimrc` was gone! Moral of the story, vim needs it's config file--wherever you put it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim), I needed to set up Vundle like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

Afterwards, the error got resolved. By the way, I am on a FreeBSD 10.3-STABLE machine not macOS

Answer (score 1):

This could be as a result of end of line characters, CRLF for windows and LF for linux.
Change your line endings.
if on unix in your `~/.vimrc` file :

`:set fileformat=unix
 :w`