# Not an editor command :PluginInstall, vim in mac osx 10.12.6

Tags: macos, vim

I have the next problem with vim, i have a Mac OsX 10.12.6 and i configure the .vimrc and when i touch the ESC button ant tipping `:PluginInstall`, tell me the next error:

```
E492: Not an editor command: PluginInstall
```

I follow the tutorial of this page https://realpython.com/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/ but, i think there is a problem, because it not working fine, beacause i can't install any Plugin with the command `:PluginInstall`
I have MacVim installed and my .vimrc is the next:

```
set nocompatible              " required
filetype off                  " required

 set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
 set splitbelow
 set splitright
 call vundle#begin()
 "split navigations
 nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>
 nnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
 nnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>
 nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>
 " Enable folding
 set foldmethod=indent
 set foldlevel=99
 " Enable folding with the spacebar
 nnoremap <space> za
 " alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
 "call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

 " let Vundle manage Vundle, required
 Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
 Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimplyFold'
 Helptags

 let g:SimplyFold_docstring_preview=1
 " PEP8 indetantion
 au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4
    \ set softtabstop=4
    \ set shiftwidth=4
    \ set textwidth=79
    \ set expandtab
    \ set autoindent
    \ set fileformat=unix
 " HTML, JS, CSS indentation
 au BufNewfile,BufRead *.js, *.html, *.css
    \ set tabstop=2
    \ set softtabstop=2
    \ set shiftwidth=2
 "Fix problem indentation PEP8
 Plugin 'vim-script/indentpython.vim'
 "Uneccesary whitespace
 au BufRead,BufNewfile *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h match BadWhitespace /\s\+$/
 " UTF8 support
 set encoding=utf-8
 "Autocomplete
 Bundle 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'

 let g:ymc_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion=1
 map <leader>g :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration<CR>

 " python with virtualenv support

 py << EOF
 import os
 import sys
 if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
     project_base_dir = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
     activate_this = os.path.join(project_base_dir, 'bin/activate_this.py')
     execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
 EOF

 " Syntax Checkin/Highlighting
 Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
 Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'
 let python_highlight_all=1
 syntax on

 "Color Shemes
 Plugin 'jnurmin/Zenburn'
 Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
 if has('gui_running')
     set background=dark
     colorscheme solarized
 else
     colorscheme zenburn
 endif
 call togglebg#map("<F5>")
 "File Browsing
 Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
 Plugin 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
 let NERDTreeIgnore=['\.pyc$','\~$'] "Ignore files in NERDTree

 "SuperSearching
 Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
 "Line numering
 set nu
 "Git integration
 Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'

 "Powerline
 Plugin 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp': 'powerline/bindings/vim/'}

 "System clipboard
 set clipboard=unnamed
 "VIM in the shell
 set editing-mode vi

 " add all your plugins here (note older versions of Vundle
 " used Bundle instead of Plugin)

 " ...

 " All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
 call vundle#end()            " required
 filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

I try change my .vimrc, but now the errors are the next:

```
dmuino@Diegos-MacBook-Pro:~$ vi .vimrc
Error detected while processing /Users/dmuino/.vimrc:
line    4:
E518: Unknown option: the 
line    8:
E15: Invalid expression: /Users/dmuino/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim)
E116: Invalid arguments for function vundle#begin
Error detected while processing function vundle#config#bundle[2]..<SNR>5_check_bundle_name:
line    1:
E121: Undefined variable: s:bundle_names
E116: Invalid arguments for function has_key(s:bundle_names, a:bundle.name)
E15: Invalid expression: has_key(s:bundle_names, a:bundle.name)
line   11:
E121: Undefined variable: s:bundle_names
line    1:
E121: Undefined variable: s:bundle_names
E116: Invalid arguments for function has_key(s:bundle_names, a:bundle.name)
E15: Invalid expression: has_key(s:bundle_names, a:bundle.name)
line   11:
E121: Undefined variable: s:bundle_names
Error detected while processing /Users/dmuino/.vimrc:
line   25:
E492: Not an editor command:  Helptags
Error detected while processing function vundle#config#bundle[2]..<SNR>5_check_bundle_name:
line    1:
E121: Undefined variable: s:bundle_names
E116: Invalid arguments for function has_key(s:bundle_names, a:bundle.name)
E15: Invalid expression: has_key(s:bundle_names, a:bundle.name)
line   11:
E121: Undefined variable: s:bundle_names
line    1:
E121: Undefined variable: s:bundle_names
E116: Invalid arguments for function has_key(s:bundle_names, a:bundle.name)
E15: Invalid expression: has_key(s:bundle_names, a:bundle.name)
line   11:
E121: Undefined variable: s:bundle_names
Error detected while processing /Users/dmuino/.vimrc:
line  109:
  File "<string>", line 1
    import os
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
Press ENTER or type command to continue
 set nu
 "Git integration
 Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'

 "Powerline
 Plugin 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp': 'powerline/bindings/vim/'}

 "System clipboard
 set clipboard=unnamed
 "VIM in the shell
 set editing-mode vi

 " add all your plugins here (note older versions of Vundle
 " used Bundle instead of Plugin)

 " ...

 " All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
 call vundle#end()            " required
 filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vundle - E492: Not an editor command: PluginInstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185580/vundle-e492-not-an-editor-command-plugininstall)

Comment: `PluginInstall` is a command of `Vundle` plugin, you have to install and configure it first. You have `call vundle#begin` commented out. Uncomment it and edit the path.

Comment: I put this :
 `call vundle#begin(/Users/dmuino/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim)`
But the problem continue

Answer (score 6):

Something may be wrong with your plugin manager [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) `:PluginInstall` or [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) `:PlugInstall`,  the next picture is for vim-plug:

[image]

You could try to install `vim-plug` by doing this:

```
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

And later modify your `.vimrc`:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
```

Check the example for more options: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#example

Comment: Actually, Vundle has a `PluginInstall` command, while vim-plug has a `PlugInstall` command (the difference being `Plugin` instead of `Plug`)

Comment: I use both plug and plugin and don't work, Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Line 4 of your file has to be a COMMENT.
So let it start with an `"`

Instead of

```
 set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
```

it has to be

```
"  set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps miss the step where you install Vundle?

This command installs Vundle to `.vim/bundle` in your home directory:

`$ git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`

Line 5 in your `.vimrc`, `set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`, tells VIM where to look for Vundle, after which line 8, `call vundle#begin()`, should run without problems.

Note that you also have a syntax error in line 4, as @Cosmic's [answer mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54998108/2264149).

Answer (score 0):

E492 is for path issue where git cloned the vundle files in wrong place. I guess you have to provide with absolute path. Vundle plugins have a lots of other issues that vim doesn't process. The best is to write your own configuration settings as you learn and apply them.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have an OSX try to follow this steps

Remove the vim you installed with homebrew (do not worry, we will install later)

```
$ brew remove vim
$ brew cleanup
```

Install vim with this homebrew command

```
$ brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim
```

check your git version to see if it is already installed

```
$ git version
```

install vundle

```
$ git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

open vim

```
$ vim
```

try

```
:PluginInstall
```